# how to upload bin file from android internal storage to http server in android

Tags: android, httpserver, bin, internal-storage

how to upload bin file from internal storage to http server in android?

I'm getting permission denied error.

```
        String url = "url_path";
        String PATH = "/storage/emulated/0/data/";
        Log.v("response path ", "PATH: " + PATH);
        File file = new File(PATH,
                "/test.bin");
        if(file.exists()){
            Log.d("response : "," file available");
        } else {
            Log.d("response : "," file not available");
        }
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                new FileInputStream(file), -1);
        reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Error Log:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/data/test.bin (Permission denied)

Answer (score 0):

**You have permissions for your App's data directory only.** unless you have rooted android device.

**or**

A **System** app.